# IEnumerable with unknown type

Tags: c#

I have a mapping class that contains a mapping of custom objects:

```
public class MappingType
{
    public Type source {get;set;}
    public Type dest {get;set;}
}
```

Why is it I can't use them as below (`mappinglist` is object of `MappingType`)?

```
IEnumerable<mappinglist[0].source,mappinglist[0].dest> customlist;
```

What are my options? How can I use it in such context?

Comment: Well for one thing, `IEnumerable<T>` only has a single type parameter...

Comment: You are trying to use values of variables, rather than using types.

Comment: IEnumerable<MappingType> why not use this?

Comment: @btevfik: My guess is he's trying to enumerate through a source list to build/update a destination list and wants a strongly typed construct for those actions.

Comment: Assuming you have 2 types (Type A and B) If you are trying to create a new list from of type B from a list of type A, you can use AutoMapper.

Comment: Why are you using Type? What were you trying to accomplish with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C# generics system works for types known at compile time.  You cannot provide types known only at runtime as type parameters.

Additionally, as @JonSkeet points out, [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx) only takes one type parameter.

If your types have anything in common (shared base class, shared interface) you can use that "thing in common" with generics, e.g.

```
IEnumerable<ISomeSharedInterface> customList;
```

If they have nothing in common, you can still use the non-generic [`IEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: thank you, i didn't know IEnumberable can only be used with known type at compile time.